# Drag and drop between overlapping views

Tags: android, android-layout, drag-and-drop

I am trying to move items between two recyclerviews, one of them into a bottom sheet.

I get this working without problems if the bottom sheet is in the same LinearLayout that the target recylcerview, as you can see in this gif:

[image]

This is the working layout:

```
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:orientation="vertical"
app:layout_constraintBaseline_toTopOf="parent"
android:gravity="center_horizontal">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:paddingTop="20dp"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:text="Target RecyclerView" />


<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/rvTop"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="16dp"
    android:paddingBottom="16dp"/>


<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <include layout="@layout/bottom_sheet_dialog" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

My problem is when I try it with the bottom sheet overlapping the main content, I mean using a FrameLayout or Relativelayout as parent. In this case onDrag() is not fired outside the bottom sheet. Not working:

[image]

Not working layout, using a RelativeLayout:

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toTopOf="parent"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:paddingTop="20dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:text="Target RecyclerView" />


        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rvTop"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="16dp"
            android:paddingBottom="16dp"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <include layout="@layout/bottom_sheet_dialog" />

    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I need the bottom sheet over the main content. Any idea?
Thanks!

Edit: Further investigations point that the problem is the CoordinatorLayout (which is a Bottom Sheet requirement). CoordinatorLayout is a "super-powered FrameLayout" and it acts at "top-level application decor", and I do not know why it does not allow onDrag events get views outside of CoordinatorLayout.

Workaround: For the moment my workaround is setting CorrdinatorLayout visibility to GONE when one of its views is dragged. This allow me to drop the view outside of CoordinatorLayout successfully, but I think should be some other way, some CoordinatorLayout parameter to allow dragging outside it.

Comment: You can put the LinearLayout inside the root RelativeLayout

Comment: Hi @Zain LinearLayout already is inside RelativeLayout. 
I have added some new info. The problem is the CoordinatorLayout. It blocks sending onDrag events to any view outside of CoordinatorLayout. However, if I make CoordinatorLayout visibility GONE after startDragandDrop (in onTouch method) all works.